# How to pass VAR from child script to parent's script running loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops, variables

I'm thinking how to solve this functionality on the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash

. script.sh &

while [ "$VAR" != "OK" ];
do
    echo -e "Waiting..."
    sleep 1
done
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
export VAR=OK
```

As the while loop runs in subshell of it's parent shell, it will never finishes as will never get the sourced `script.sh` `export VAR=OK`.

Any ideas how to pass the `VAR` value to the while loop ?

NOTE: I need to run the `script.sh` in background.

Thanks !

Comment: I would suggest having the parent script check for the existence of a file in each pass of the loop, and read the contents if it exists. It can then remove the file. Have the child process write the file.

Comment: Are you trying to wait for the child to complete, or wait for the child to supply you with some data? Is the while loop going to do some other things while waiting?

Answer (score 1):

child

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 2                   # wait 2 seconds
echo "OK"
```

parent

```
#!/bin/bash
answer=$(mktemp)          # create a tempfile
./script.sh & >$answer    # start script in background, output in tempfile
wait $!                   # wait for script.sh finished
var=$(cat $answer)        # read anwser in variable 
echo $var                 # echo anwser
rm $answer                # cleanup - remove tempfile
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

child:

```
sleep 1
echo blah >> $varfile
```

parent:

```
#make sure varfile exists and is empty..
echo > varfile

#run script in background
./script.sh &

# wait for some output:
VAR=$( ( tail -f varfile & )  | sed "/.*$/q")
echo >> varfile;
```

Just to explain a bit of trickery here:

`tail -f` is used to capture the output.   This call does not terminate when it hits the end of the file, but instead, sits and waits for more to be written to the file (which is what you want... at first...).   When it receives a complete line, it will output it, and then wait for then next line.   The trick is it does not terminate under normal circumstances.  Instead, it will continue to run until either someone does a ctrl-c or it detects a broken pipe.   This must be pushed to be a background task, otherwise the command in the script would never terminate.   It's output is piped into `sed`.   `sed` on the other hand will terminate when it receives a valid end of input (due to the `$` in the pattern), and when it does, execution of the script continues.   But notice that `task` is still running at this point, and will continue to run until it attempts to push something to the now-broken pipe.  To prevent it from running indefinitely, we output something to it after sed terminates, at which point it realizes the pipe is broken, and terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Unix/Linux systems have great support for inter-process communication. In this case I think what you're looking for is signalling. For instance you could do something like this:

```
foo &
FOO_PID=$!
# do other stuff
kill $FOO_PID
```

if it's important that the loop complete before the process exits you can [trap](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) that signal and set `VAR=OK` when you receive that signal

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using process Substitution

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=$(. script.sh &)

while [ "$VAR" != "OK" ];
do
    echo -e "Waiting..."
    sleep 1
done
```

script.sh

```
$VAR=OK
echo $VAR
```

Answer (score -1):

parent.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
   if [ -e /tmp/var_file ]; then
      VAR=$(cat /tmp/var_file)
      echo "VAR is $VAR"
      rm -f /tmp/var_file
   fi
   sleep 1
done
```

child.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "SUCCESS" > /tmp/var_file
```